# Completing Source[ByteString, _] in Akka-Http

Tags: scala, akka-http, akka-stream

I wanted to use Alpakka for handling S3 upload and download with Akka Steams. However, I got stuck with using Source produced by S3Client within Akka Http routes. The error message I get is:

```
[error]  found   : akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,_$1] where type _$1
[error]  required: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
[error]     complete(source)
```

I assume that it is some annoying trivial thing, like missing implicit import, but I was not able to pinpoint what I am missing.

I've created some minimal example to illustrate the issue:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import akka.util.ByteString

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class Test {

  implicit val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  val route = (path("test") & get) {
    def source: Source[ByteString, _] = ??? // just assume that I am able to get that value
    complete(source) // here error happens
  }

  Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8000)
}
```

Do you have some suggestions, what can I try? I am using

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka"%% "akka-http" % "10.0.5"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create an `HttpEntity` from the source, and give it a content-type.

```
complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, source))
```

Comment: More specifically, `HttpEntity.Default`. "It has a known length and presents its data as a Source[ByteString]".

Comment: Thanks! I was confused by second paragraph of http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html . I (mis)understood that there is some implicit conversion that I am missing.

Comment: I see. Further implicits are only necessary if you want to stream custom classes directly, converting them to JSON under the hood.